# Angular 16.2 migration & jest unit tests no more working

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest

I've migrated our corporate project from angular 12 to 16. Everything works fine but unit tests while running jest.
I suspect a ts compiler / module import misconfiguration issue but can't find out where.
The error thrown is :

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  1 | import 'jest-preset-angular';
> 2 | import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
    | ^
  3 |

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-preset-angular/setup-jest.js:2:24)
  at Object.<anonymous> (setup-jest.ts:2:1)
```

Our configuration files :

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "builddev": "ng build",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production && gzipper compress ./dist",
    "buildint": "ng build --configuration integration && gzipper compress ./dist",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "jest --runInBand",
    "test:coverage": "jest --runInBand --coverage",
    "docs:json": "compodoc -p ./tsconfig.json -e json -d .",
    "lint": "eslint \"**/*.{ts,tsx}\"",
    "test:ci": "jest --ci --runInBand --config ./jest.config.js --watchAll=false --collectCoverage --coverageDirectory=\"./coverage\"",
    "lint:ci": "eslint \"**/*.{ts,tsx}\" --format junit --output-file=test_report/lint_junit.xml"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "16.2.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.22.10",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "6.1.8",
    "@ngrx/component-store": "16.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "16.2.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "16.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "16.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "16.2.0",
    "@stomp/rx-stomp": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/clone": "2.1.1",
    "bpmn-js": "13.2.2",
    "dayjs": "1.11.9",
    "dayjs-ext": "^2.2.0",
    "fast-copy": "^3.0.1",
    "humanize-duration": "^3.29.0",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "0.2.4",
    "primeicons": "6.0.1",
    "primeng": "16.2.0",
    "reselect": "^4.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslib": "2.6.1",
    "zone.js": "0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "16.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "16.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "16.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "16.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "16.2.1",
    "@angular/elements": "16.2.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.1.21",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "7.3.2",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "7.3.2",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "7.3.2",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "7.3.2",
    "@storybook/addon-jest": "7.3.2",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "7.3.2",
    "@storybook/angular": "7.3.2",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "7.3.2",
    "@storybook/cli": "7.3.2",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "6.5.16",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "0.2.0",
    "@types/humanize-duration": "^3.27.1",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.3",
    "@types/jquery": "3.5.16",
    "@types/node": "20.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.4.0",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "1.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.4",
    "eslint": "8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "9.0.0",
    "gzipper": "7.2.0",
    "jest": "29.6.2",
    "jest-junit": "16.0.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "13.1.1",
    "prettier": "3.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false, /* Added for TS2564 */
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2021", /* NOT using 2022 as not supported by @ngrx/store */
    "module": "es2022",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": { /* https://ichi.pro/fr/comment-configurer-tsconfig-json-options-typescript-strictes-175839645691938 */
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.spec.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "CommonJs",
    "types": [
      "jest", // 1
      "node"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true, // 2
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true // 3
  },
  "files": [
    "src/setup-jest.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "jquery"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.stories.*",
    "node_modules/bpmn-js/lib/model/Types.ts",
    "node_modules/diagram-js/lib/model/Types.ts",
    "node_modules/diagram-js/lib/util/Types.ts"
  ]
}
```

**setup-jest.js**

```
import 'jest-preset-angular';
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
```

note :
VsCode complains on the two lines above :

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'jest-preset-angular'. '/home/adaje/projects/cdmv2/peach/frontend/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/build/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jest-preset-angular` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'jest-preset-angular';`ts(7016)

Could not find a declaration file for module 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest'. '/home/adaje/projects/cdmv2/peach/frontend/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/setup-jest.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jest-preset-angular` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';`ts(7016)
```

I'm trying to install that package but it fails as not found. Actually that @types package is not found in npm repo.

**jest.config.js**

```
const { defaults } = require('jest-config');

module.exports = {

  bail: 1, // Arrête de lancer les tests après 1 échec

  verbose: true,

  roots: ['<rootDir>'],

  preset: "jest-preset-angular",

  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    "<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"
  ],
  globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup',

  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/",
    "/dist/"
  ],

  modulePaths: [
    "<rootDir>"
  ],
  moduleDirectories: [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    ...defaults.moduleFileExtensions,
    "js", "json", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "node", "mjs"
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  },

  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true,
      tsconfig: "tsconfig.spec.json",
      stringifyContentPathRegex: "\\.html$"
    }
  },

  reporters: [
    "default",
    [
      "jest-junit",
      {
        suiteName: "jest tests",
        outputDirectory: "test_report",
        outputName: "peach_jest_junit.xml"
      }
    ]
  ],

  transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/(?!bpmn-js|diagram-js)"],

  collectCoverage: false, // Informations de couverture seront collectées lors des tests
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "src/**/*component.ts",

    "!**/node_modules/**",
    "!**/stories/**",
    "!**/generated/**",
    "!**/poc/**",
    "!src/app/app.component.ts",
  ],

  coverageDirectory: "<rootDir>/coverage", // Dossier où sera écrit les fichiers de couverture
  coverageReporters: ["html", "text", "text-summary", "json", "cobertura"],
  coverageThreshold: {
    "global": {
      "branches": 0,
      "functions": 0,
      "lines": 0,
      "statements": 0
    }
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "frontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "peach",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "path-intersection",
              "dayjs",
              "dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat",
              "inherits"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "subresourceIntegrity": true
            },
            "integration": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.int.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```